# PHP Dynamic URLs that work for shared headers in subfolders (for use in live hosting and development)

Tags: php, url, dynamic

I am trying to generate dynamic url's with PHP to allow me to use shared headers across subdirectories that link to assests like images and css files wherever they are within the site. My PHP isnt strong so please excuse any lingo that is off!

I have managed to achieve all of what I'm looking for apart from automatically generating the url containing the site folder.

I want this to work automatically on both my local development environment (Wamp) as well as a live deployment.  I want to automatical add the subfolder on a dev environment.

This is what is working well so far:

```
<?php 
  $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
  $domain_name = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  $site_url = $protocol.$domain_name;

  define("BASE_URL", $site_url . '/CompanyName/'); 
?>

<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>
```

I want to autogenerate the final piece where '/CompanyName/' is. That is the folder containing the site files.  It may or may not be required depending upon the server environment.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to configure things differently according to the server environment, this is typically done via setting (and then retrieving) environment variables.  Alternatively, your code could check for the existence of a file or directory and branch accordingly.  Please could you clarify the intended logic behind 'may or may not be required depending upon the server environment'?

Comment: _"It may or may not be required depending upon the server environment."_ - let me guess - because you are using `http:/localhost/CompanyName/` to access your project in the local dev environment? You should rather set up a proper virtual host then, so that you can access it via a local domain name, such as `http://companyname.local/` - then you can use the same _relative_ URLs for your assets, between your local dev and your live system. (Or you can still use absolute ones, if you like - just the dynamic insertion of that extra folder name isn't necessary any more.)

Comment: If @CBroe is correct then look at [The WAMPServer Help site](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757) For a note on Virtual Hosts and how to set them up

Comment: Thank you all for responding.  CBroe - Thanks, yes that just clicked in my mind as most efficent/best option.  Thank you for jogging my memory.  I have taken  long break from any web development to that was a perfect reminder.  Cheers!